# Como testar um número e dizer se é primo ou não?

Tags: c

Estou com um pequeno problema, após a primeira vez que o código executa ele só mostra "NOT PRIME" e não mostra mais "PRIME", onde "NOT PRIME", seria para números não primos, e "PRIME" para números primos.

```
  #include <stdio.h>
  main()
  {

    int i, x=1; 
    int div = 0;

    while(x!=0)
    {
      do
      {
        printf("\n\t\tEntre com numero inteiro e positivo: \n\n");
        scanf("%d", &x);
      } while (x <= 0);   
      for (i = 1; i <= x; i++)
       {
        if (x % i == 0)
        { 
         div++;
        }
      }     
      if (div == 2)
      {
        printf("\t\t\nPRIME\n", x);
      }
      else
      {
        printf("\t\t\nNOT PRIME\n", x);
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: lembre de atribuir 0 a variável div.

Answer (score 1):

Podes usar esta função para verificar se o número é primo:

```
#include <stdio.h>

/* Retorna 1 para numeros primo ou 0 para numeros que nao sao primos.*/
int IsPrime(unsigned int number) {
    if (number <= 1) return 0; // se o numero for menor ou igual a 1 então nao é primo.
    unsigned int i;

    for (i = 2;  i * i <= number; i++) {
        if (number % i == 0) return 0;
    }

    return 1;
}

int main(void) {
    printf("0 é primo %s\n", IsPrime(0) ? "sim" : "nao");
    printf("1 é primo %s\n", IsPrime(1) ? "sim" : "nao");
    printf("3 é primo %s\n", IsPrime(3) ? "sim" : "nao");
    printf("2 é primo %s\n", IsPrime(2) ? "sim" : "nao");
    printf("4 é primo %s\n", IsPrime(4) ? "sim" : "nao");
    printf("5 é primo %s\n", IsPrime(5) ? "sim" : "nao");
    printf("7 é primo %s\n", IsPrime(7) ? "sim" : "nao");
    printf("9 é primo %s\n", IsPrime(9) ? "sim" : "nao");

    return 0;
}
```

Saída:

> 0 é primo nao
>   1 é primo nao
>   3 é primo sim
>   2 é primo sim
>   4 é primo nao
>   5 é primo sim
>   7 é primo sim
>   9 é primo nao

Esta função `IsPrime()` pode ser facilmente utilizada em um loop, e não terá um alto custo na manutenção, veja:

```
int i, v;

for(i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    printf("Informe um numero: ");
    scanf("%i", &v);

    printf("%i é primo %s\n",v , IsPrime(v) ? "sim" : "nao");
}
```

Não é necessário fazer o calculo de verificação do numero dentro do mesmo loop que faz a leitura dos valores digitados pelo usuário, é sempre um bom caminho criar funções separadas para executar determinadas tarefas, desta forma você pode reaproveita-la e usar ela em outras lugares.

E também temos que garantir o tratamento dos números digitados pelo usuário, por isso o uso do `unsigned` para números sem sinal, e a validação do numero no inicio, porém, é necessário fazer outras validações dos dados antes de mandar para a função `IsPrime()` fazer a verificação do número.

Veja funcionando no [Ideone](https://ideone.com/0mJ5EB).

[Fonte](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1538653/5429980).

Answer (score 0):

Bastava igualar o `div` a zero sempre que o `while` for completado, além disso, no segundo `while` troquei a condição para `x < 0` dado que zero seria o número para o programa se encerrar.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {

    int i, x; 
    int div;

    do {

        do {
            printf("\n\t\tEntre com numero inteiro e positivo: \n\n");
            scanf("%d", &x);
        } while (x < 0);   

        for (i = 1; i <= x; i++)
            if (x % i == 0)
                div++; 

        if(x != 0) {
            if (div == 2)
                printf("\t\t\nPRIME\n", x);
            else
                printf("\t\t\nNOT PRIME\n", x);
        } 

        div = 0;

    }while(x != 0);

    return 0;
}
```

No mais corrigi detalhes, como identação, retorno, etc.